# How to align columns with same name in r?

Tags: r

I have different columns with same column names.

In the first data; each column has 16 rows.

```
longdata<-structure(list(X2012 = c(0, 0.4, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 1.8, 0.8, 
3.6, 0.2, 0, 0.8, 4, 5.6, 4.2), X2013 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X2014 = c(0.4, 0.6, 
0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0)), .Names = c("X2012", 
"X2013", "X2014"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))
```

In the second data, each column has 6 rows.

```
shortdata<-structure(list(X2012 = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2), X2013 = c(0, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0), X2014 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("X2012", 
"X2013", "X2014"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

And here is what I want to do;

```
finaldata<-structure(list(X2012 = c(0, 0.4, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 1.8, 0.8, 
3.6, 0.2, 0, 0.8, 4, 5.6, 4.2), X2012.1 = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X2013 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    X2013.1 = c(0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), X2014 = c(0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 
    0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0), X2014.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("X2012", 
"X2012.1", "X2013", "X2013.1", "X2014", "X2014.1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `rowr::cbind.fill`, make the names unique using `make.unique` and `order` them.

```
df1 <- rowr::cbind.fill(longdata, shortdata, fill = NA)
names(df1) <- make.unique(names(df1))
df1[order(names(df1))]


#   X2012 X2012.1 X2013 X2013.1 X2014 X2014.1
#1    0.0     0.2     0     0.0   0.4       0
#2    0.4     0.4     0     0.2   0.6       0
#3    0.8     0.6     0     0.0   0.6       0
#4    0.2     0.2     0     0.0   0.0       0
#5    0.0     0.2     0     0.2   0.0       0
#6    0.0     0.2     0     0.0   0.0       0
#7    0.2      NA     0      NA   0.4      NA
#8    1.8      NA     0      NA   0.2      NA
#9    0.8      NA     0      NA   0.2      NA
#10   3.6      NA     0      NA   0.0      NA
#11   0.2      NA     0      NA   0.2      NA
#12   0.0      NA     0      NA   0.0      NA
#13   0.8      NA     0      NA   0.0      NA
#14   4.0      NA     0      NA   0.2      NA
#15   5.6      NA     0      NA   0.0      NA
#16   4.2      NA     0      NA   0.0      NA
```

---

In base R you could use `match` the row numbers and `cbind`

```
cbind(longdata,shortdata[match(seq_len(nrow(longdata)), seq_len(nrow(shortdata))),])
```

You might need to use `make.unique` to make names unique in this case as well.

Answer (score 4):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
longdata %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 left_join(shortdata %>%
            rowid_to_column(), by = c("rowid" = "rowid"), suffix = c("", ".1")) %>%
 select(-rowid)
```

Here it performs a left join based on row ID.

```
   X2012 X2013 X2014 X2012.1 X2013.1 X2014.1
1    0.0     0   0.4     0.2     0.0       0
2    0.4     0   0.6     0.4     0.2       0
3    0.8     0   0.6     0.6     0.0       0
4    0.2     0   0.0     0.2     0.0       0
5    0.0     0   0.0     0.2     0.2       0
6    0.0     0   0.0     0.2     0.0       0
7    0.2     0   0.4      NA      NA      NA
8    1.8     0   0.2      NA      NA      NA
9    0.8     0   0.2      NA      NA      NA
10   3.6     0   0.0      NA      NA      NA
11   0.2     0   0.2      NA      NA      NA
12   0.0     0   0.0      NA      NA      NA
13   0.8     0   0.0      NA      NA      NA
14   4.0     0   0.2      NA      NA      NA
15   5.6     0   0.0      NA      NA      NA
16   4.2     0   0.0      NA      NA      NA
```

Or the same idea with `base R`:

```
longdata$rowid <- seq_along(longdata$X2012)
shortdata$rowid <- seq_along(shortdata$X2012)

merge(longdata, shortdata, by = "rowid", all = TRUE, suffixes = c("", ".1"))[, -1]
```

Or even more simplified (proposed by @Ronak Shah):

```
merge(longdata, shortdata, by = "row.names", all = TRUE, suffixes = c("", ".1"))[, -1]
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah that is a nice and clever simplification, thank you :)